# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Issue

Tags: ios, swift, layout, cell, collectionview

I have tried to create self-sizing collectionView `cell`, but my label doesn't want to expand his height and become multilines, instead the label just goes in one single line and my cell goes beyond of collectionView frame. I have created my own custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout and tried to handle all stuff there. What have I done wrong? Looking forward for your answers, thanks!

My implementation:

```
class VerticalLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
    self.scrollDirection = .vertical
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 173)
    self.sectionInset = .zero
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check number of lines of label. label.numberOfLines must be zero.

Comment: UILabel constraints look like: https://imgur.com/a/9juaXhe

Comment: @phani numberOfLines set to zero of course

Comment: I think your flow layout is not working. Return cell size (350, 1000). If you get multiple lines then your flow layout is not working.

Comment: I just tried to set numberOfLines to 5 and result is still the same

Comment: with auto layouts you can't get dynamic height. You need to calculate it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must count text height and pass it to your collectionview delegate method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let itemHeight: CGFloat = estimatedHeightForText(text: items[indexPath.item].text, fontSize: fontSize, fontWeight: fontWeight, width: widthForText) + someRawValue // here count height for cell
    var itemWidth: CGFloat = someRawVal

    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)

}
```

Count it here

```
    func estimatedHeightForText(text: String, fontSize: CGFloat, fontWeight: UIFont.Weight, width: CGFloat) -> CGRect {

    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 1000)
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: fontWeight)

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
}
```

**UPD.** widthForText - this is important value for text width in your cell. Count it properly